# Converting an iterative loop to a function

Tags: python, list, function, loops, for-loop

I am new to python trying to learn with examples

I want to convert an for loop to an function in python Is it possible for this loop

```
group= [(1,2,3,4),(3,3,4,5)]

i = 0
for cell in group:
    x,y,w,h = cell[0],cell[1],cell[2],cell[3]
    I=[y+h,x+w]
    i=i+1
    print(I)
```

Can anyone help me converting this loop as an function

O/p for this loop is :

```
[6, 4]
[8, 7]
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Loops and functions are completely separate concepts. You don't convert one to the other.

Comment: Cant I get the same output using functions from the lists @Selcuk

Comment: My question is like I want to get the same output using functions could you please help me @Selcuk

Comment: A function is just a wrapper of code, the loops will still be there

Comment: @azro yes so I can use it anywhere thats why I am asking could you please help me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Putting the code inside a function, does change anything to the block of code itself, it just wraps it

```
def my_method(values):
    i = 0
    for cell in values:
        x, y, w, h = cell[0], cell[1], cell[2], cell[3]
        I = [y + h, x + w]
        i = i + 1
        print(I)


my_method([(1, 2, 3, 4), (3, 3, 4, 5)])
```

Note that loop can be reduced, as `i` isn't use, and some inlining can be done

```
def my_method(values):
    for x, y, w, h in values:
        print([y + h, x + w])
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```python
def my_loop_function(group):
    i = 0
    is=[]
    for cell in group:
        x,y,w,h = cell[0],cell[1],cell[2],cell[3]
        I=[y+h,x+w]
        i=i+1
        is.append(I)
    return(is)
```